# Livequery doesn't find element in a first look

Tags: jquery, livequery

I have a button that is generated dynamically and I want to get the click event in this button.

So, I coded this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#editDescription').livequery('click',function(){
        alert('click');
    });
});
```

But it did not work.

So, I try the following to see if the element is seen by the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').livequery('click',function(){
        console.log($('#editDescription'));
    });
});
```

And it worked, the element was there. So I did that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').livequery('click',function(){
        $('#editDescription').livequery('click',function(){
            alert('click');
        });
    });
});
```

And after the second click, started to alert.
Why this happens and what can I do to correct this?

Thanks!